# aiohttp schedule run task in background

Tags: python, aiohttp

For exaple:

```
async def first_route(request):
    ......

async def second_route(request):
    ......
    
async def functionToSchedule():
    ......
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/fr', first_route)
    app.router.add_post('/sr', second_route)
    web.run_app(app)
```

I cant understand, how i can add task to run `functionToSchedule` every day at `00:00`.
If i use simple `schedule` library, i cant paste call of function after `web.run_app(app)`

Comment: `web.run_app()` is a infinite loop, it will never stop until the program is terminated so functions after it will never be called.

Comment: @mousetail i understand that. Thats why i ask my question) How i can add schedule for this construction

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to write a function that will run every day at 00:00 (and you are aware that depending on your apps load this time might not be precise), so I'll just concentrate on adding the task.

### First way

the more direct one is based on the fact that you can pass a loop argument to `web.run_app(app, loop=loop)` and do stuff with it before that. So it would go something like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/fr', first_route)
    app.router.add_post('/sr', second_route)

    # get the loop and add a task
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(function_to_schedule())

    # pass the loop to run_app
    web.run_app(app, loop=loop)
```

### Second (probably better) way

and this is the one that is suggested in the [official aiohttp documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#background-tasks) is to use `app.cleanup_ctx` like this (there is an example in the documentation):

```
async def background_tasks(app):
    app['function_to_schedule'] = asyncio.create_task(
        function_to_schedule()
    )
    yield
    app['function_to_schedule'].cancel()
    await app['function_to_schedule']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/fr', first_route)
    app.router.add_post('/sr', second_route)

    app.cleanup_ctx.append(background_tasks)

    web.run_app(app)
```